# Right way to nest models and routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, nested

I created a **Bar** model nested inside a **Foo** , routing and relationship is already working. i can create multi **bar**s relative to the parent **Foo**

```
#foo model
class Foo< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

#bar model
class Bar< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end

#nested routing
resource :foo do
 resource :bar
end


#Beautiful draw

|Foo1___
|       |__Bar1
|Foo2___
|       |__Bar1
|       |__Bar2
|       |__Bar3
|Foo3___
|       |__Bar1
|       |__Bar2_
|               |
```

now i need to create 4 more models that are logically childres of a Bar but this deep nesting approach seems cumbersome to me, especially because i may need to add another level below some of them

```
  resources :foo do
    resources :bar do
      resources :donatello
      resources :raphael do
        resources :pizza
      end
      resources :michelangelo
      resources :leonardo

    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually doing this properly.

We have some nested resources that are 7 - 9 levels deep.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: ok great,is enought to say that michelangelo belongs_to :bar, or should i have it belongs to :foo also?